# Unable to plot line in the animation

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have created an animated line in Matplotlib which moves from left to right of the curve using my script below:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

X =  #Time scale in milliseconds, converted to seconds       

# Data to plot the curves
Y1 = data_orig[410:524,4]
Y2 = data_orig[410:524,3]
Y3 = data_orig[410:524,2]

plt.plot(X, Y1, 'r--', X, Y2, 'b--', X, Y3, 'g--')
plt.grid(True)

plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Force [N]')

X_MIN = 0.0  //0
X_MAX = 0.6  //600
Y_MIN = -300
Y_MAX = 1500
X_VALS = np.arange(X_MIN, X_MAX+1);


def update_line(num, line):
    i = X_VALS[num]
    line.set_data( [i, i], [Y_MIN, Y_MAX])
    return line,

#l , v = plt.plot(0, -200, 600, 1500, linewidth=2, color= 'gold')
l , v = plt.plot(0.0, -200, 0.6, 1500, linewidth=2, color= 'gold')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, len(X_VALS), fargs=(l, ), interval=15, blit=False, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

**Problem:** The line works if the values in X_MIN and X_MAX is set to 0 and 600 respectively. But when I divide this by 1000(to convert to seconds, the line disappears. There is no error which pops as well.

*Before (with 0 and 600)*

[image]

*After (with 0.0 and 0.6)*

[image]

What I am doing wrong? How could I solve this?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I will try to figure out how to reduce this code in a few lines.

Comment: Hint: in animation functions error do not show up, but you can insert e.g. some print commands within the function. Maybe there are better ways to debug such codes, but for me this worked most times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem lies in the following line:

```
X_VALS = np.arange(X_MIN, X_MAX+1);
```

You did not specify some step size, therefore when X_MIN and X_MAX is 0 and 0.6, X_VALS only is an array with two entries, [0, 1]

So, a possible minimal version works pretty well:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def update_line(num, line):
    i = X_VALS[num]
    line.set_data([i, i], [Y_MIN, Y_MAX])
    return line,


X_MIN = 0.0
X_MAX = 0.6
Y_MIN = -300
Y_MAX = 1500
step_size = 0.01

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([X_MIN, X_MAX], [Y_MIN, Y_MAX], 'r--',)
plt.grid(True)

plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Force [N]')

X_VALS = np.arange(X_MIN, X_MAX + step_size, step_size)

l, v = plt.plot(0.0, -200, 0.6, 1500, linewidth=2, color= 'gold')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, len(X_VALS), fargs=(l, ), interval=15, blit=False, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed that detail. Thanks again, worked well!